# Java Scanner Array

Tags: java

I am having troubles with java. I need to scan numbers (example: `1 3 4 2 5 6 7`) and put them into array. The problem is I don't know how long it will be. Is there a command that I can use to determine the length of the numbers putted in scanner?

Comment: Most scanning devices I've worked with act as a keyboard, and just "type" whatever you scan.  So you can just grab all the input and then parse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use ArrayList, as a workaround, I advice to read the entire line and then split to get the length and individual values:

```
   String line = scanner.nextLine();
   String[] values = line.split(" ");
   int[] intValues = new int[values.length];
   int indx = 0;
   for(String value:values){
     intValues[indx++] = Integer.parseInt(value);
   }
```

**EDIT**: Second approach:

```
   List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   int number = 0;
   while (number != -1) {
      System.out.println("Enter a positive integer value (or -1 to stop): ");
      number = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
      if (number != -1){
        numList.add(number);
      }
   }
   in.close();

   Integer[] numArray = numList.toArray(new Integer[numList.size()]);
```

**EDIT2:**  Taking care of multiple numbers in the same line and terminating at empty line

```
List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while(true) {
   System.out.println("Enter a positive integer value (or -1 to stop): ");
   String line = in.nextLine();
   if(line.length() <1){
      break;
   }
   String [] numbers = line.split(" ");
   for(String num: numbers){
          numList.add(Integer.parseInt(num));
   }
 }
 in.close();

 Integer[] numArray = numList.toArray(new Integer[numList.size()]);
```

Comment: what about if input would be in this shape:
1
3
2
8
5
(every number in her own line?)

Comment: @user1791473: You have couple of options. First: Define as big enough array if you know the max input size. Accept all the inputs and truncate the array in the end, if partially filled. Second: Use the open ended collection e.g. List and convert to array in the end (suggested in other answers). If you plan to use option one and need help, please let me know.

Comment: i'll go with the second one, just having problems with scanner - i don't know how to tell him to top reading without knowing how many lines it will have. i tried with hasNextLine, but it doesn;t work...

Comment: @user1791473: Added the answer for second approach.

Comment: i'm not allowed to use that option. The input are simply numbers each one in it-s own line...

Comment: @user1791473: Updated to use the `nextLine()`. This will stop as soon as you enter `-1`.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using -1? the scanner would only take the given numbers...

Comment: @user1791473: You need to define some termination condition. `-1` is just one example. You may use any condition you like. Please share, what condition you want to use?

Comment: can a condition be an empty row?

Comment: @user1791473 Yes. Updated the `EDTI2` section in the answer. Please check. Now it will terminate on `empty line` only.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [**ArrayList**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) if you want a variable-size collection.

```
ArrayList<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<Integer>();
lst.add(scanner.getInt());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `ArrayList`. Just fill it up and at the end, convert it to an integer array. Or even better, keep the list and work with that.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (true) {
  System.out.println("Enter a positive integer value (or -1 to stop): ");
  int number = in.nextInt();
  if (number < 0) break;
  intList.add(number);
}
// just use this last line if you really want an array. Work with the list instead if possible.
Integer[] yourFinalArray = intList.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the google Guava library ( https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/ ) you can say:

```
String numbers="1 3 4 2 5 6 7";
Splitter.on(" ").split( numbers );
```

this gives you an iterable. If you insist on getting an array of Strings, you can say:

```
Iterables.toArray(Splitter.on(" ").split( numbers ), String.class)
```