# Input numeric ranges with java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, arrays, input, java.util.scanner

I would input numeric ranges (`int` arrays with two elements) like this:

Enter a number: 3
Enter a range: -3 5
Enter a range: 0 4
Enter a range: 6 10

I use `java.util.Scanner`, but I do not know how to proceed:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = input.nextInt();

    for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
        String str = input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any relation to C++; Removed the tag

Comment: You seem to know how to use `nextInt()`. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I don`t know how to make an input like this one => enter a number: 2 then enter range x y = > enter range z k

Comment: After reading `number` you should create a 2D array to store ranges: `int[][] ranges = new int[number][2]; ` then in the loop read int values using `input.nextInt()` and assign to the range using nested loop: `for (int j = 0; j < ranges[i].length; j++) {ranges[i][j] = input.nextInt();}`

Answer (score 0):

I think, you just nead a solution for input a numeric array. Check out this: [Java Scanner Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178354/java-scanner-array)

You can read the whole line, then split it into a `String` array:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try (var scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {

    System.out.print("Enter the count of arrays: ");
    int arrayCount = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();

    // System.out.print("Enter the length of an array: ");
    int arraySize = 2;

    int[][] ranges = new int[arrayCount][arraySize];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++) {
      System.out.printf("[%d] Enter the elements: ", i);
      String line = scanner.nextLine();
      String[] numbers = line.split("\\D+", arraySize + 1); // separator: 1+ non-digit

      for (int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++) {
        ranges[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[j]);
      }
    }
    // Arrays.stream(ranges).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

Or simply scan `int`s one-by-one:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try (var scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {

    System.out.print("Enter the count of arrays: ");
    int arrayCount = scanner.nextInt();

    // System.out.print("Enter the length of an array: ");
    int arraySize = 2;

    int[][] ranges = new int[arrayCount][arraySize];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++) {
      System.out.printf("[%d] Enter the elements: ", i);
      for (int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++) {
        ranges[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
      }
    }
    // Arrays.stream(ranges).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```